# How can I remove certain icons that I don't use in the Control panel from view?

Tags: windows-vista, control-panel

How can I remove certain icons that I don't use in the Control panel from view? My control panel is fairly cluttered up and I would like to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own! This post shows how to use a bunch of chosen shortcuts in a folder that you can put where you want.

http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/06/10/how-to-create-a-custom-control-panel-for-windows-vista/

Answer (score 3):

For Windows XP, you can remove Control Panel items using the [TweakUI Microsoft PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx).

I don't know if there's anything similar for Vista, but you can also [use Group Policy Editor](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t56.html) for Vista/Windows 7.

Comment: +1 for both TweakUI and Group Policy Editor.  The accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question!  

The linked page on Group Policy Editor isn't the clearest thing I've ever read.  For one thing, the page suggests using the "Show only specified items" when I think most people would want to use the "Hide Specified Items" policy unless this is being done for security reasons.  For another, it isn't clear from the description, but Group Policy Editor accepts both filenames (main.cpl) and friendly names (Mouse).